# How do I call another function in lisp;

Tags: lisp

My program is supposed to convert a given temperature from Fahrenheit to Centigrade or the other way around.  It takes in a list containing a number and a letter.  The letter is the temperature and the letter is the unit we are in.  Then I call the appropriate function either F-to-C or C-to-F.  How do I call the functions with the given list that was first checked in my temperature-conversion function. Here is my code.

```
 (defun temperature-conversion (lst)
  (cond
  ((member 'F lst) (F-to-C))
  ((member 'C lst) (C-to-F))
  (t (print "You didn't enter a valid unit for conversion"))
  )
)
(defun F-to-C ()
;;(print "hello")
 (print (temperature-conversion(lst)))
)   
(defun C-to-F ()
(print "goodbye"))  
;;(print (temperature-conversion '(900 f)))
(setf data1 '(900 f))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have infinite recursion: `temperature-conversion` calls `F-to-C` which calls `temperature-conversion` again.

I would do this:

```
(defun c2f (c) (+ 32 (/ (* 9 c) 5)))
(defun f2c (f) (/ (* 5 (- f 32)) 9))
(defun temperature-conversion (spec)
  (ecase (second spec)
    (C (c2f (first spec)))
    (F (f2c (first spec)))))
(temperature-conversion '(32 f))
==> 0
(temperature-conversion '(100 c))
==> 212
(temperature-conversion '(100))

*** - The value of (SECOND SPEC) must be one of C, F
      The value is: NIL
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this example is generally used to demonstrate how functions are first-class values.

With a little modification to [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184664/124319), you can have an [`ECASE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm) statement that selects the appropriate function, which is then used by a surrounding [`FUNCALL`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm).

```
(defun temperature-conversion (spec)
  (destructuring-bind (temperature unit) spec
    (funcall
      (ecase unit (C #'c2f) (F #'f2c))
      temperature)))
```

I added a [`DESTRUCTURING-BIND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_destru.htm) in case you don't know yet what it is.