# Lisp equals not working as expected

Tags: lisp

I am slowly getting more comfortable with this language. But I am having an issue... I am working on a function that converts a temperature to either celcius or F. I am passing in a list as such (50 C) and then handling each case seperate. For some reason, when I do (equalp "C" (cadr lst)) I am getting NIL.I printed out the cadr of the list and it is C. Any Ideas?

```lisp
(defun convert-to-c(num)
    (* (- num 32) 5/9)
)

(defun convert-to-f(num)
    (+ (* num 9/5) 32)
)

(defun convert-temp (lst)
    (cond ((equalp "C" (cadr lst)) (convert-to-f (car lst)))
    (t (convert-to-c (car lst))))
)
```

The call I am making

```
(convert-temp '(30 C))
```

Comment: Hard to answer without looking at the actual code.  But certainly `C` (the symbol) is not equal to `"C"` (a string).

Comment: We'll need to see how `convert-temp` is being called also.

Comment: Fahrenheit, Celsius? check http://stackoverflow.com/q/36184100/124319

Comment: Not worried about my logic, just trying to figure out why this comparison is failing coredump

Comment: (meta. about code snippets: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283108/abusing-the-code-snippet-for-wrong-languages)

Comment: my bad on that ^ Just wanted the pretty formatting =/, I see now it'sjust indent w/ 4 spaces so in the future I will just do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're calling `convert-temp` as `(convert-temp '(30 C))` as per your comment, then `(cadr lst)` is `C`, a symbol, but you're comparing it to `"C"`, a string.

So you need to either compare symbols in `convert-temp`: `(equalp 'C (cadr lst))`

Or pass in a string:  `(convert-temp '(30 "C"))`

Symbols are typically compared with `eq`, so in the first case you could say `(eq 'C (cadr lst))`.

Comment: really appreciate it Sean =)

Comment: This is very, very important! In Lisp, we do not do run-time string processing just to have unique identifiers for labeling things in our data. When Lisp reads your `C` token, it converts that to an object, whose name is the string `"C"`, but is relatively unimportant.  The `EQ` test is an efficient comparison that is usually implemented by comparing two machine words (often address-sized ones, i.e. pointers).  `(eq 'c (cadr lst))` means, is the `CADR` of the list **the same object** as the symbol `C`? In low-level terms: do these two values point at the same piece of memory in the heap.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to compare strings and symbols:

```
(string= 'c "C")
=> T
```

But you should probably compare against a symbol with `EQ`, or simply with a case:

```
(ecase ...
  (c (c2f ...))
  (f (f2c ...)))
```